# How to update Blazor static layout from code

Tags: c#, authorization, blazor

I have a main layout with a sidebar that differs for authorized and non-authorized users. The place which I want to update looks like that

```
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                // Personal information matches in this component (it's just one more div this some code in it)
                <UserInfo />
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <div class="sidebar-unathorized">
                    <span>
                        To get all privileges, <a href="/register"><strong>register</strong></a> or <a href="/login"><strong>login</strong></a> please
                    </span>
                </div>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
```

After user passes authorization I want him to see his personal information so in my login method I do some stuff like

```
public async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    ...
   ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authenticationStateProvider).AuthenticateUser(authorizedUser);
   navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
   //here I want to update the layout
    ...
    return;
}
```

and in my CustomAuthenticationStateProvider after setting the current user I do 
   `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));`
which i hoped would be enough to all components which are authorization-based to update.
But it's not. I tried StateHasChanged() method but understanably it doesn't work like that cause it just updates the component which it's triggered from. But if u manually reload the page after logging in all will be ok. Any ideas how can I update the layout from code?

Comment: Check out [this blog post](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/2019-01-04_mvvm-support-in-blazor/) from Jeremy Likeness. He discusses a method of creating a wrapper to invoke StateHasChanged based on model updates, and since scoped services are treated like a user specific singleton, you could use one together with Jeremy's ViewRegion component to bind an event and trigger StateHasChanged further up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure about the layout of your MainLayout, so let us suppose for this answer's shake that the AuthorizeView component is embedded within the NavMenu component, itself embedded in the MainLayout component...

You want to refresh the content of the NavMenu component, which is embedded in the MainLayout component, from the login page, right?

You can use various methods to achieve this. The following solution is based on the App State Pattern.

First off, we have to create a service class that can be accessed from both, the NavMenu component and the Login component. Here's the class:

```
public class AppState
{
private bool _loggedIn;
public event Action OnChange;
public bool LoggedIn
{
    get { return _loggedIn; }
    set {
        if (_loggedIn != value)
        {
            _loggedIn = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }
 }

 private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

This class defines an event delegate, named OnChange, which should encapsulate the method that will refresh the NavMenu. This delegate is invoked when the boolean property LoggedIn's value changes. The LoggedIn property's value may change in the Login page, when the user has been logged in, thus any subscriber to this delegate, in our case, the NavMenu, will be notified of this.

### Login Page

- `@inject AppState AppState`
  Note the above inject the AppState to the Login Page. Put it at the top of the page
- `AppState.LoggedIn = true;` that code should be place at the end of the log in procedure. This will initiate the triggering of the OnChange delegate.

### NavMenu component

- `@inject AppState AppState`
- `@implements IDisposable`

*

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    AppState.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    AppState.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

Now, whenever you log in, the AppState service notifies the NavMenu component to re-render so that the content of the Authorized in the AuthorizeView is rendered.

### Startup class

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
```

Comment: Much appreciated for your answer. It's really simple but sadly it doesn't work. I implemented that approach and StateHasChanged method is being triggered then u log in but nothing changes. Are you sure that  StateHasChanged should rerender the layout?

Comment: It should work. I've already tested it. Try the following: In your login method, just set AppState.LoggedIn = true; and see if the NavMenu component is refreshed. Don't execute the login in code.

Comment: Okey, you're right. I checked if it's really rerendering and it does. It just renders the block of code in <NonAuthorized> for some reason. But after the manual refresh it renders code in <Authorized>. Anyways u answered the question so thank you but if u have any ideas why this may happen i'll be twice as thanksful.

Comment: "It just renders the block of code in <NonAuthorized> for some reason." This means that 1. my code does the work it was created fro. 2. There is some issue with your login logic. In that case I's suggest you create a new answer, and post all the relevant code.

Comment: The delay might be related to this: public async void HandleValidSubmit() use Task instead of void and report if I'm correct.

Comment: No, excpecedly it didn't help. I seemed to find the reason why it doesn't work but I have no idea how to fix it. As far as I understood while debugging, the reason is that when StateHasChanged method is executed, it doesn't trigger GetAuthenticationStateAsync for some reason method, but manual reload does.

Comment: worth noting:
AppState.LoggedIn = false;
//login logic
AppState.LoggedIn = true;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need DI, if the class that generates the event is static. An example. Let's say you want to swap the language from a component, in NavMenu. Create a class AppStatus in root

```
public static class AppStatus
{
    public static event Action OnChange;
    // sample
    public static string Culture { get; set; } = "en-US";

    public static void UpdateLanguage() => NotifyStateChanged();

    static void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

NavMenu.razor:

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Blazor Multilanguage @AppStatus.Culture</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>
// ...
// add item
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="set-lang">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Set Language
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;
    private void ToggleNavMenu() => collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    // subscribe event 
    protected override void OnInitialized() => AppStatus.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    public void Dispose() => AppStatus.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

Create component SetLanguage.razor:

```
@page "/set-lang"
<h3>SetLanguage</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeLanguage">Toggle Language</button>

@code {
    void ChangeLanguage()
    {
        AppStatus.Culture = AppStatus.Culture == "en-US" ? "ru-RU": "en-US";
        AppStatus.UpdateLanguage();
    }
}
```

When clicked the button, then NavMenu update the state... I only illustrated the part that solves the question consulted

Comment: Note. NavMenu.razor uses @implements IDisposable.